# Objective-Zip cannot open Zip

Tags: ios, zip

I have problem with Objective-Zip. It throw exeption when validate my zip. I checked file it's fine, no problems with unzip/zip. What's more I try zip my files with system default archiver and other.

I use `ZipFile *unzipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:@"textPack.zip" mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];`

Validate method

```
- (id) initWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName mode:(ZipFileMode)mode {
    if (self= [super init]) {
        _fileName= [fileName retain];
        _mode= mode;

        switch (mode) {
            case ZipFileModeUnzip:
                _unzFile= unzOpen([_fileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                if (_unzFile == NULL) {
                    NSString *reason= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't open '%@'", _fileName];
                    @throw [[[ZipException alloc] initWithReason:reason] autorelease];
                }
                break;

            case ZipFileModeCreate:
                _zipFile= zipOpen([_fileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], APPEND_STATUS_CREATE);
                if (_zipFile == NULL) {
                    NSString *reason= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't open '%@'", _fileName];
                    @throw [[[ZipException alloc] initWithReason:reason] autorelease];
                }
                break;

            case ZipFileModeAppend:
                _zipFile= zipOpen([_fileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], APPEND_STATUS_ADDINZIP);
                if (_zipFile == NULL) {
                    NSString *reason= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't open '%@'", _fileName];
                    @throw [[[ZipException alloc] initWithReason:reason] autorelease];
                }
                break;

            default: {
                NSString *reason= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unknown mode %d", _mode];
                @throw [[[ZipException alloc] initWithReason:reason] autorelease];
            }
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you use NSASCIIStringEncoding for unzopen, but UTF8 everywhere else? (this is not related to your problem, just a general comment).

Comment: Ohh.. it's only a typo, use only for testing, but that didn't help.

Comment: If you search google for unzOpen you will find another post here of someone having the same problem. Try zipping a single text file, see if that works. If not there is another framework around, less easy to use (and older), to extract zip files (multiple files too) from an archive: ZipArchive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ZipFile *unzipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:@"textPack.zip" mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
```

Won't work because @"textPack.zip" is no valid file.
The "FileName" has to include the path. I think they used a misleading name here.

Use this if your file is from the main bundle:

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"textPack" ofType:@"zip"];
ZipFile *unzipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:path mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Even if that file is added as resource?

Comment: I've added tips how to do that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I allways thought that @"text" will work but,as we can... will not.

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't work. My zip file contains a lot of subfolders and files (images:jpg,png, sounds, plists, etc...). This library can unzip it?

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with the 64 bit mode that objective-zip can use.

If you just add `legacy32BitMode:YES` when creating the archive, everything will be fine.

```
OZZipFile *zipFile= [[OZZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath 
                                                   mode:OZZipFileModeCreate 
                                        legacy32BitMode:YES];
```